# In Java, mutiple select queries or join, which one would be a better practice?

Tags: java, mysql, database, join

I have five tables in MySQL database, each of them has the one-to-one relationship with the User table that stores the username and password, there is a user_id field in User table as the foreign key for all the other tables.

If I need to implement a "Login" function with Java, to get all data of a certain user from all these five tables, would it be a good practice to use JOIN to query these five tables at once?

I also have another question, would it be a better choice to combine these five tables together as one single table as they have one-to-one relationship?

Comment: Note: don't store plain text passwords. Use key derivation functions or at minimum salted hashed with unique salt per user.

Answer (score 0):

As general principle, 1 to 1 relationships should be in the same table.

Exceptions can include:

- privilege separation - mysql users have different table level access.
- locking separation, one table as a particularly high updated field than for a userid that needs to be separate from another table of
  high userid updates.
- performance - row size - one table has large number of columns that isn't frequently needed, so keep it out of the innodb buffer pool by
  keeping those columns in a different table.

Comment: Thank you for your response! In this case I separate the table into multiple differenct tables due to the consideration of performance. If I also have few other tables that the main User table has 1-to-many relationship with, is there a efficient way to query for all those data?

Comment: I should of quantified the performance with this is really for rather exceptional cases. Don't just use it because you think its going to be better. You'll only run into this is you run a high turnover on the innodb buffer pool, and the less used fields are quite large and largely unused. For one-to-many, ensure you [have the right indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html). [DBA exchange](dba.stackexchange.com/) is a more database focused forum.

Answer (score 0):

Idea behind creating multiple tables with foreign key reference is to support one-to-many relationship. Since your table data has one-to-one relationship, there is no point creating multiple table if number of columns including all tables, having one-to-one relationship, is less than Mysql table column count limit.

Incase your business requirement doesn't allow to change the current schema, you can go for join to get all the data in single network call rather than making multiple network call to get data as network call latency is not predictable.

Comment: Thank you for your response! The reason to split them into multiple tables is because some of the columns are not frequently used as the others. However, it looks like using JOIN to query these five tables together seems to be a reasonable way. If I have few more tables that the User table has 1-to-many relationship with, would using JOIN be a efficient way to query them?

Comment: Database engine tries to fetch data in optimal way if table is created in proper way with required constraints/indices and will be far better than multiple network call which is unpredictable.